# Bind arrow keys to Buefy pagination

Tags: vue.js, buefy

Is there a built in way to bind arrow keys (right, left) to the buefy pagination element? Or do I need to use the vanillaJS keyboard events?

Answer (score 1):

Vue defines [key modifiers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Key-Modifiers)

```
<button v-on:keyup.left="goPrevious" />
<button v-on:keyup.right="goNext" />
```